# How to compare Real Fourier Transform implementation from Numerical Recipes to Matlab fft?

Tags: c, signal-processing, fft

I'm calculating discrete Fourier transform using Numerical Recipes and (to confirm the result) Matlab. Working with real values only.

My Matlab code

```
in(1)=0.0;
in(2)=1.0;
in(3)=2.0;
in(4)=3.0;
in(5)=4.0;
in(6)=5.0;
in(7)=6.0;
in(8)=7.0;

out = fft(in);
```

gives me

```
out =
 28.0000 + 0.0000i
 -4.0000 + 9.6569i
 -4.0000 + 4.0000i
 -4.0000 + 1.6569i
 -4.0000 + 0.0000i
 -4.0000 - 1.6569i
 -4.0000 - 4.0000i
 -4.0000 - 9.6569i
```

What `data` input do I need to send to Numerical recipes

```
void realft( float data[], unsigned long n, int isign ){...}
```

in order to get the same output as Matlab?

From this [NR forum](http://numerical.recipes/forum/showthread.php?t=1539) link, I found out that input to `realft` needs to be shifted one place, so I am using `in[0] = 0`, and consequently input is 1 element larger than N.

Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 8
int main()
{
  float inout[LEN+1];

  inout[0] = 0.0;
  inout[1] = 0.0;
  inout[2] = 1.0;
  inout[3] = 2.0;
  inout[4] = 3.0;
  inout[5] = 4.0;
  inout[6] = 5.0;
  inout[7] = 6.0;
  inout[8] = 7.0;

  realft( inout, LEN, 1 );

  for( unsigned int i=0; i<LEN+1; i=i+1)
      printf("%15.10f \n",inout[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Output from the test code is:

```
 0.00000000 
28.00000000
-4.00000000
-4.00000000 
-9.65685463
-4.00000000
-4.00000000
-4.00000000
-1.65685427
```

which is similar, but different from Matlab.

`realft` is taken from Numerical Recipes (uses `four1` routine):

Comment: how different? Show us a [mcve]

Comment: Edited, have a look.

Comment: Edited again, removed the code due to possibly copyright problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first aspect that is different between Matlab and Numerical Recipes' implementations, other than the off-by-one indexing that you've already noticed and accounted for, is that they are based on a slightly different definition of the FFT. More specifically, [Matlab uses a negative complex exponential for the forward transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#buuutyt-6) while Numerical Recipes uses a positive complex exponential. Correspondingly Numerical Recipes' implementation would give a result that is the complex conjugate of that from Matlab.

The other thing is that those implementations produce a result in a different packing order, and Numerical Recipes' implementation only outputs the non-redundant lower half of the spectrum. Graphically, this mapping could be represented (after changing the sign of the imaginary parts in accordance with the previous point with respect to complex conjugation) by the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Is it simple to change the NR algorithm to provide the same non-complex conjugate result as Matlab?

Comment: Could this also explain why the complex result between numerical recipes and FFTW has an opposite sign?

Comment: @benrules2 yes, Matlab and FFTW use essentially the same definition (other than 0-based vs. 1-based indexing convention)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Follow up Q if you don't mind... Is there any significance to using negative or positive complex exponential, or is it simply a convention you must stick to?

Comment: @benrules2 Simply a matter of convention

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refer to the source code of realft(). It seems that there is something wrong in using this function. The reason is, although the input is in real values, the values of the spectrum are generally complex. However, in your program, the results are returned from the original inout, which is in real data type, and the imaginary part are discarded.

Answer (score 0):

For the two examples, you have different inputs (similar but different).  For the matlab example, your input was a ramp from 0->7 inclusive.  But because of indexing differences (which someone else alluded to), in the C implementation, your input was a 0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6 (as opposed to 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7).   If you are doing a bunch of matlab to C, the difference in the array indexing (matlab starts at 1, C starts at 0).